# EEL , OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, html, eel

```
import eel

import time

eel.init('web')

@eel.expose <br>
def getTime():<br>
      return "Hello World" <br>

eel.start('main.html')<br>
```

This is a simple program to return hello world in main.html file, I am using Windows 10 and generating the error

```
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

When using Ubuntu or MAC it is not generating any error

Comment: Use `\`\`\`` instead of `'''` for code formatting

Comment: What are the <br> in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
eel.start('index.html', mode='default')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply